# How long time should it take for service fabric to go from deploying->autoscale->ready?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

From the output below its seen that the cluster is still in "deploying" mode, waiting for the "autoscale"->"ready" states to kick in. But looking at the nodes, they been running with nodestatus = 1 for 20min.

Is it possible to get some insights into what triggers that step from deploying to autoscale->ready?

Is time correlated with size of node machines?

```
C:\Users\pks>armclient get /subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4?api-version=2016-03-01
{
  "type": "Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "id": "/subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4",
  "name": "citestcluster4",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-resourceType": "Service Fabric",
    "hidden-clusterName": "citestcluster4"
  },
  "etag": "W/\"636020077930324002\"",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "clusterId": "909e26fe-3d44-4bf9-942d-dea6d37b0b2c",
    "clusterCodeVersion": "5.1.150.9590",
    "clusterState": "Deploying",
    "managementEndpoint": "https://citestcluster4.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19080",
    "clusterEndpoint": "https://westeurope.servicefabric.azure.com/runtime/clusters/909e26fe-3d44-4bf9-942d-dea6d37b0b2c",
    "certificate": {
      "thumbprint": "4BE52A76D3E63B159F8475B56B40D29D20584FF5",
      "x509StoreName": "My"
    },
    "clientCertificateThumbprints": [],
    "clientCertificateCommonNames": [],
    "fabricSettings": [
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "ClusterProtectionLevel",
            "value": "EncryptAndSign"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountConfig": {
      "storageAccountName": "h7vokscadqdiy2",
      "protectedAccountKeyName": "StorageAccountKey1",
      "blobEndpoint": "https://h7vokscadqdiy2.blob.core.windows.net/",
      "queueEndpoint": "https://h7vokscadqdiy2.queue.core.windows.net/",
      "tableEndpoint": "https://h7vokscadqdiy2.table.core.windows.net/"
    },
    "vmImage": "Windows",
    "reliabilityLevel": "Silver",
    "nodeTypes": [
      {
        "name": "nt1vm",
        "placementProperties": {
          "isPrimary": "true",
          "vmNodeTypeSize": "Standard_A0"
        },
        "capacities": {
          "memory": "100"
        },
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": true,
        "vmInstanceCount": 5,
        "durabilityLevel": "Bronze"
      }
    ]
  }
}
C:\Users\pks>armclient get /subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4/nodes?api-version=2016-03-01
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4/Nodes/_nt1vm_2",
      "properties": {
        "Name": "_nt1vm_2",
        "IpAddressOrFQDN": "10.0.0.6",
        "Type": "nt1vm",
        "CodeVersion": "5.1.150.9590",
        "ConfigVersion": "1",
        "NodeStatus": 1,
        "NodeUpTimeInSeconds": "1276",
        "HealthState": 1,
        "IsSeedNode": true,
        "UpgradeDomain": "2",
        "FaultDomain": "fd:/2",
        "Id": {
          "Id": "2153dcef983f79f6d056f74e724abf00"
        },
        "InstanceId": "131108866624879337",
        "NodeDeactivationInfo": {
          "NodeDeactivationIntent": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationStatus": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationTask": [],
          "PendingSafetyChecks": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4/Nodes/_nt1vm_0",
      "properties": {
        "Name": "_nt1vm_0",
        "IpAddressOrFQDN": "10.0.0.4",
        "Type": "nt1vm",
        "CodeVersion": "5.1.150.9590",
        "ConfigVersion": "1",
        "NodeStatus": 1,
        "NodeUpTimeInSeconds": "1275",
        "HealthState": 1,
        "IsSeedNode": true,
        "UpgradeDomain": "0",
        "FaultDomain": "fd:/0",
        "Id": {
          "Id": "310a2a579b75d9847ba5a43d6b365d7c"
        },
        "InstanceId": "131108866767599090",
        "NodeDeactivationInfo": {
          "NodeDeactivationIntent": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationStatus": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationTask": [],
          "PendingSafetyChecks": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4/Nodes/_nt1vm_3",
      "properties": {
        "Name": "_nt1vm_3",
        "IpAddressOrFQDN": "10.0.0.7",
        "Type": "nt1vm",
        "CodeVersion": "5.1.150.9590",
        "ConfigVersion": "1",
        "NodeStatus": 1,
        "NodeUpTimeInSeconds": "1275",
        "HealthState": 1,
        "IsSeedNode": true,
        "UpgradeDomain": "3",
        "FaultDomain": "fd:/3",
        "Id": {
          "Id": "899b5afa0a70e1af4a620eda67d0260f"
        },
        "InstanceId": "131108866347571432",
        "NodeDeactivationInfo": {
          "NodeDeactivationIntent": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationStatus": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationTask": [],
          "PendingSafetyChecks": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4/Nodes/_nt1vm_4",
      "properties": {
        "Name": "_nt1vm_4",
        "IpAddressOrFQDN": "10.0.0.8",
        "Type": "nt1vm",
        "CodeVersion": "5.1.150.9590",
        "ConfigVersion": "1",
        "NodeStatus": 1,
        "NodeUpTimeInSeconds": "1268",
        "HealthState": 1,
        "IsSeedNode": true,
        "UpgradeDomain": "4",
        "FaultDomain": "fd:/4",
        "Id": {
          "Id": "bde184b3d9f49b2af32e8037eb951483"
        },
        "InstanceId": "131108867572806882",
        "NodeDeactivationInfo": {
          "NodeDeactivationIntent": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationStatus": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationTask": [],
          "PendingSafetyChecks": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourcegroups/ci-sf-tests4/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/citestcluster4/Nodes/_nt1vm_1",
      "properties": {
        "Name": "_nt1vm_1",
        "IpAddressOrFQDN": "10.0.0.5",
        "Type": "nt1vm",
        "CodeVersion": "5.1.150.9590",
        "ConfigVersion": "1",
        "NodeStatus": 1,
        "NodeUpTimeInSeconds": "976",
        "HealthState": 1,
        "IsSeedNode": true,
        "UpgradeDomain": "1",
        "FaultDomain": "fd:/1",
        "Id": {
          "Id": "de98611a5345b01b365ee8e6d67bfcad"
        },
        "InstanceId": "131108870541748899",
        "NodeDeactivationInfo": {
          "NodeDeactivationIntent": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationStatus": 0,
          "NodeDeactivationTask": [],
          "PendingSafetyChecks": []
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your cluster too small? Standard_A0 (which is what I think I read) is not that big and it could just be that it is taking a long time.

Comment: Thats a comment, not an answer to any of the questions asked if you ask me.

Comment: I sort of agree, but it could be the answer. Someone else had an issue with too small a cluster on another question. I did debate about writing a comment or an answer. If it turns out not to be an answer, at least I can remove it!